# pascalTriangle and Venn Diagrams

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, pascals-triangle, scopus, eulerr

I have downloaded results from scopus of papers by doing various queries for each topic. The downloaded singleton papers are identified by EID. I would like to see where the intersections are, i.e., if there are any overlaps (e.g., if those found with query 1 are also found in the cluster found with query 2, etc.) and if there are any overlaps.
I would then need to do a pascalTriangle to see the matrix of intersections and then a Venn diagram.

I am attaching figures of the outputs I would need.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see this method: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/vignettes/introduction.html.
But I have 20 cluster and I am not able to find the intersection.
The cluster are from 1 to 10 and I have to find  "1&2" = n1, "1&3" = n2 and so on.

Comment: Please try to avoid posting follow-ups to your questions in the Answers section. Instead, add an EDIT: message to your original post.